# Formatting text in RichtextBox WPF

Tags: wpf, text, richtextbox, formatting

I try formatting text in richTextBox, something like in skype chat.

```
1.column-"Nick"         2.column-"Text of Messange"                3.column-"DateTime"
```

I want alling 1. column max left and 3. column max right.

What is the best way how can I do it? I am using WPF.

Comment: Why are you using a single RichTextBox (instead of three (Rich)TextBlocks)?

Comment: I think this is no good solution, for example if you have full are of richtextbox, u must scrolling 3 richtetbox, also you have also trouble with line height in richtextboxes....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**My solution:**

Simple solution is create Table object and add to blocks of richtextbox, somothing like this:

```
        var tab = new Table();

        var gridLenghtConvertor = new GridLengthConverter();

        tab.Columns.Add(new TableColumn() { Name = "colNick", Width = (GridLength)gridLenghtConvertor.ConvertFromString("*") });
        tab.Columns.Add(new TableColumn { Name = "colMsg", Width = (GridLength)gridLenghtConvertor.ConvertFromString("5*") });
        tab.Columns.Add(new TableColumn() { Name = "colDt", Width = (GridLength)gridLenghtConvertor.ConvertFromString("*") });

        tab.RowGroups.Add(new TableRowGroup());
        tab.RowGroups[0].Rows.Add(new TableRow());

        var tabRow = tab.RowGroups[0].Rows[0];


        tabRow.Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run(rpMsg.Nick))) { TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Left });

        tabRow.Cells.Add(new TableCell(ConvertToRpWithEmoticons(rpMsg.RpText)));

        tabRow.Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run("Cas"))) { TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Right });

        RtbConversation.Document.Blocks.Add(tab);
```